# What is the serial comms protocol for the DCF77 receiver module from HKW named FUM DCF-U

Tags: dcf77

There is no reply from the supplier (in Germany), nor any hit from my searches.
The module has a simple RS232 connection which allows interrogation of the module to get 'atomic' date&time info, but details of the protocol are nowere to be found.
I need the protocol documentation. https://www.hkw-shop.de/out/media/FMD01031R_FUM_DCF-U_DD.pdf

Answer (score 0):

## The supplier now provided this information:

Data Exchange of Radio Controlled Clocks (RC Clocks) equipped with a PC 
serial interface

1. Introduction

The serial interface consists of one data input line and one data output line. 
The data traffic speed of the serial interface is 300 bps. Because of the 
limited resources of the RC Clock micro-controller only an easy software 
protocol can be used. There are no hand shake lines. Synchronising to the 
host is by means of the character echo.

2. Voltage supply of the serial interface

The RC Clocks with serial interface are battery operated radio controlled 
clocks which are powered by two 1.5V cells. This ensures a battery life of 
approximately two years. The voltage supply of the serial interface is 
independent of these batteries.
The RS232 serial standard interface consists not only of the serial input 
(RxD) and output (TxD) lines but also some additional lines which are used 
in some applications for handshaking purposes, the RC Clock uses these 
additional lines to supply its internal serial interface circuit with the 
required electrical voltage. These additional lines are not needed for data 
exchange.
The RC Clock requires both a positive and a negative voltage out of the 
PC's serial interface.

The positive voltage is supplied by the DTR line.

There are two ways of providing the negative voltage:

a) The PC "communicates" with the RC Clock by sending ASCII characters 
to the RC Clock as described below (see 5.). This allows the negative 
voltage to be provided by the TxD line. When the PC sends characters this 
line is toggled between a positive and negative voltage level. If the PC 
is waiting for the RC Clock to reply the TxD line is always low at a 
negative voltage. The RC Clock does not need the TxD negative voltage 
while receiving characters only while sending.

b) The RC Clock can be triggered to transmit the time/date 
information by pulling the data input line to high voltage level as 
described below (see 3.3). This line must be held high until the data 
transmission out of the RC Clock has begun. Therefore it cannot supply 
the negative voltage. The possibility exists to supply the negative 
voltage out of the RTS line. This line must be set to low level by 
the programmer who wants to cause the RC Clock to transmit the time/date 
information by holding TxD at high voltage level.

3. Data word format

3.1. Data transmitted to the RC Clock

3.1.1. Interface parameters

a) MSF Version
            Speed:    300 bps
   Data Bit Count:    7
           Parity:    even, odd, mark, space 
                      (not checked by the RC Clock)
   Stop Bit Count:    2

b) DCF77 Version
            Speed:    300 bps
   Data Bit Count:    8
           Parity:    none
   Stop Bit Count:    2

3.1.2. Function of data input

The RC Clock accepts commands of up to three characters, including 
its parameters. The character carriage return (hex 0d) causes the RC 
Clock to execute the command. Only the four lower bits of each command 
and parameter character are used. For instance the characters "?", "O" 
and "o" have the same effect. The exception is the final carriage return 
which is completely decoded by considering the seven lower bits (MSF 
version) resp. all of the eight bits (DCF77 version).

3.2. Replies of the RC Clock

3.2.1. Interface parameters

```
         Speed:  300 bps
Data Bit Count:  7
    Parity Bit:  even
Stop Bit Count:  2
```

3.2.2. Function of data output

The reply of the RC Clock consists of a sequence of ASCII characters 
terminated by a final carriage return character .
The character set used by the RC Clock is limited to the numbers 
0 ... 9 and the characters : ; < = > ?. The information is contained 
within the four lower bits.
The bits 4 and 5 of every reply character are binary ones, the bit 6 is 
binary zero and the bit 7 contains the even parity bit. This results in 
the sixteen different characters transmitted by the RC Clock, as 
described above.
The serial output of the RC Clock can not be interrupted during its 
reply. Therefore all characters must be taken by the host computer 
immediately.

3.3. Support of a simplified data exchange

A simplified data exchange is possible.
The time/date information transmit command (( o  ) see below 5.1.) is 
not the only way to initiate a sequence of ASCII characters. A simpler 
method is to pull the TxD (TxD of the PC) voltage level high. Normally 
TxD voltage level is low (inactive). If the TxD line is high at the start 
of a second then the RC Clock will transmit its time/date information. 
This can takes up to one second because the first start bit of the time/date 
information sets the beginning of a second. If the TxD line is held high 
continually then the RC Clock will transmit the time date information 
every second. But care must be taken: The current consumption of the RC 
Clock increases during the time/date information output (duration 
approximately. 600 ms) up to 200 ÊA.

4. Handshaking

Every character received by the RC Clock is echoed. The next character 
must not be transmitted to the RC Clock before the echo of the preceding 
character and an additional duration of 10 ms.
Recognising input characters is by checking the correct appearance both 
of the start bit and the two stop bits. The eight echoed data bits remain 
unchanged under all circumstances, regardless whether or not parity is 
even or odd.

5. Description of commands

The commands 5.7. to 5.11. (set and read alarm times) are related to
desktop alarm-clocks.

5.1. Transmit time/date information local time

syntax ASCII: o

Character "o" may be replaced if necessary by a character whose code contains 
the lowest four bits f(hex), e.g. also / ? O _

syntax binary: xxxx1111 00001101

The RC Clock replies to this command with a sequence of 15 characters 
which contain the complete time information and a final . Making 16 
characters in total.
The RC Clock will not reply immediately to this command because the 
start bit edge of the first reply character marks the beginning of the 
second. So the RC Clock will reply to this command at the start of the 
next second.

The characters have the following meaning:
      1. hours tens
      2. hours units
      3. minutes tens
      4. minutes units
      5. seconds tens
      6. seconds units
      7. day of week 1 (Monday) ... 7 (Sunday)
      8. day of month tens
      9. day of month units
     10. month tens
     11. month units
     12. year tens
     13. year units
     14. summer/winter status
         bit7  parity
         bit6  always 0
         bit5  always 1
         bit4  always 1
         bit3  always 0
         bit2  =1 if standard time is in effect
         bit1  =1 if summer time is in effect
         bit0  summer/winter time change impending bit =1 in case of change impending
     15. status
         bit7  parity
         bit6  always 0
         bit5  always 1
         bit4  always 1
         bit3  =1 if low battery voltage is detected
         bit2  MSF Version  : don't care
               DCF77 Version: =1 if the first reception attempt failed 
                              and still no valid time information exists 
                              (bit0 = 0)
                              The first succsessful reception attempt resets
                              this bit.
         bit1  =1 if the latest reception attempt was successful
               =0 if the latest reception attempt was not successful
         bit0  =1 if the RC Clock contains a valid time information
                  This bit is zero after reset and one after the first 
                  successful reception attempt.

5.2. Transmit time/date information UTC

syntax ASCII: u

Character "e" may be replaced if necessary by a character whose code contains 
the lowest four bits 5(hex), e.g. also e E

syntax binary: xxxx0101 00001101

The RC Clock replies to this command with a sequence of 15 characters 
which contain the complete UTC time information and a final . Making
16 characters in total.
The RC Clock will not reply immediately to this command because the 
start bit edge of the first reply character marks the beginning of the 
second. So the RC Clock will reply to this command at the start of the 
next second.

The characters have the following meaning:
      1. hours tens
      2. hours units
      3. minutes tens
      4. minutes units
      5. seconds tens
      6. seconds units
      7. day of week 1 (Monday) ... 7 (Sunday)
      8. day of month tens
      9. day of month units
     10. month tens
     11. month units
     12. year tens
     13. year units
     14. BST/UTC status
         bit7  parity
         bit6  always 0
         bit5  always 1
         bit4  always 1
         bit3  always 0
         bit2  =1 if standard time is in effect
         bit1  =1 if summer time is in effect
         bit0  summer/winter time change impending bit =1 in case of change impending
     15. status
         bit7  parity
         bit6  always 0
         bit5  always 1
         bit4  always 1
         bit3  =1 if low battery voltage is detected
         bit2  MSF Version  : don't care
               DCF77 Version: =1 if the first reception attempt failed 
                              and still no valid time information exists 
                              (bit0 = 0)
                              The first succsessful reception attempt resets
                              this bit.
         bit1  =1 if the latest reception attempt was successful
               =0 if the latest reception attempt was not successful
         bit0  =1 if the RC Clock contains a valid time information
                  This bit is zero after reset and one after the first 
                  successful reception attempt.

5.3. Transmit clock status

syntax ASCII: f

Character "f" may be replaced by a character whose code contains the 
lowest four bits  6, e.g. also 6 F V v

syntax binary: xxxx0110 00001101

The reply to this command consists of four characters and the final . 
The characters have the following meaning:

```
  1. tens of the count of hours since the latest successful signal pick up
  2. ones of the count of hours since the latest successful signal pick up
  3. status informations
      bit7 parity
      bit6 always 0
      bit5 always 1
      bit4 always 1
      bit3 =1 for DCF77 version
           =0 for MSF version
      bit2 don't care
      bit1 don't care
      bit0 switching status,
           alarm time 1 switches to 1
           alarm time 2 switches to 0
  4. ASCII "0"
```

5.4. Transmit reception status

syntax ASCII: g

Character "g" may be replaced by a character whose code contains the 
lowest four bits  7, e.g. also ' 7 G W w

syntax binary: xxxx0111 00001101

The reply to this command consists of two characters and the final . 
The characters have the following meaning:
      1. Status of reception
          bit7 parity
          bit6 always 0
          bit5 always 1
          bit4 always 1
          bit3 always 0
          bit2 always 0
          bit1 always 1
          bit0 =0 if no reception attempt takes place at the moment
               =1 if a reception attempt takes place at the moment
      2. reception quality characterising number from 0 to 5
          5 indicates a good reception without any disturbances
          0 indicates very poor reception conditions
            If the number is in the range from 0 to 2 no successful 
            reception is to be expected normally.
            During reception pauses this number is always 0.

5.5. Start reception attempt

syntax ASCII: h

Character "h" may be replaced by any other character whose code contains 
the lowest four bits 8, e.g. also ( 8 H X x

syntax binary: xxxx1000 00001101

This command causes the RC Clock to activate the receiver IC and to 
start a reception attempt. 
If this attempt ends unsuccessfully bit 1 of the 15th time/date information
character will be reset (see 5.1. and 5.2). This bit is set after completing
the reception attempt successfully.

5.6. Start reception attempt

syntax ASCII: i

Character "i" may be replaced by any other character whose code contains 
the lowest four bits 9, e.g. also ) 9 I Y y

syntax binary: xxxx1001 00001101

This command is for compatibility reasons and does the same like "h" (see 5.5).

5.7. Transmit alarm times

syntax ASCII: j

Character "j" may be replaced by a character whose code contains the lowest 
four bits  a(hex), e.g. also * : J Z z

syntax binary: xxxx1010 00001101

The RC Clock replies to this command with a sequence of 8 characters 
which contain both alarm times and a final . Time 1 corresponds to 
alarm time 1, time 2 corresponds to alarm time 2.
The characters have the following meaning:
      1. time 1, hours tens
      2. time 1, hours units
      3. time 1, minutes tens
      4. time 1, minutes units
      5. time 2, hours tens
      6. time 2, hours units
      7. time 2, minutes tens
      8. time 2, minutes units

All characters contain the following bits:
      bit7 parity
      bit6 always 0
      bit5 always 1
      bit4 always 1
      bit3 n3
      bit2 n2
      bit1 n1
      bit0 n0

Bits n3...n0 contain the according numbers 0 ... 9 in BCD code. To 
deactivate one of the times bit 3 of the corresponding hours tens is to 
be set. Therfore the hours tens may contain not only 0, 1 or 2 but also 
8, 9 and a(hex).

5.8. Set hours of alarm time 1

syntax ASCII:   k

Character "k" may be replaced a character whose code contains the lowest 
four bits  b(hex), e.g. also + ; K [

syntax binary: xxxxt3t2t1t0  xxxxu3u2u1u0  xxxx1011  00001101

This command causes the RC Clock to take over the two parameters which 
are the  and  into the hours register of alarm time 1.
To deactivate alarm time 1 bit t3 is to be set.
Attention: If parameters of this command are omitted the corresponding 
hours register will be undefined.

5.9. Set minutes of alarm time 1

syntax ASCII:   l

Character "l" may be replaced by a character whose code contains the 
lowest four bits  c(hex), e.g. also , < L \

syntax binary: xxxxt3t2t1t0  xxxxu3u2u1u0  xxxx1100  00001101

This command causes the RC Clock to take over the two parameters which 
are the  and  into the minutes register of alarm time 1.
Attention: If parameters of this command are omitted the corresponding 
minutes register will be undefined.

5.10. Set hours of alarm time 2

syntax ASCII:   m

Character "m" may be replaced by a character whose code contains the 
lowest four bits  d(hex), e.g. also - = M ]

syntax binary: xxxxt3t2t1t0  xxxxu3u2u1u0  xxxx1101  00001101

This command causes the RC Clock to take over the two parameters which 
are the  and  into the hours register of alarm time 2.
To deactivate alarm time 2 bit t3 is to be set.
Attention: If parameters of this command are omitted the corresponding 
hours register will be undefined.

5.11. Set minutes of alarm time 2

syntax ASCII:   n

Character "n" may be replaced by a character whose code contains the 
lowest four bits  e(hex), e.g. also . > N ^

syntax binary: xxxxt3t2t1t0  xxxxu3u2u1u0  xxxx1110  00001101

This command causes the RC Clock to take over the two parameters which 
are the  and  into the minutes register of alarm time 2.
Attention: If parameters of this command are omitted the corresponding 
minutes register will be undefined.

6. Testing of the interface

By means of a simple terminal program the function of the serial interface
can be tested. Here are parameters for Windows Terminal which are analogous
to other terminal programs:
  - 300 Baud data speed
  - 7 data bits
  - Parity "space"
  - 2 stop bits
  - Protocoll none

## - Interface: depends on the chosen serial interface (e.g. Com1:)